# Closure Compiler, how to stop converting arrow functions to regular functions

Tags: google-closure-compiler

```
let test = () => { return true; }
```

becomes

```
var test=function(){return!0};
```

but I want to keep the arrow function (checking for ES6 support). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Transpilation is controlled by the language flags. You'll need `--language_out=ECMASCRIPT_2015` (or higher) to keep arrow functions as that is the first Ecmascript version that supports arrow functions.

Comment: // @language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT_2015' at https://closure-compiler.appspot.com had no effect.

Comment: Apparently this Appspot version has a problem. It works otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: add `// @language_out ECMASCRIPT_2015` to the header on closure-compiler.appspot.com.